# Can i call a method from another project that use an @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Im trying to call a method from a second project that i import with a dependency.

This method is wrapped in a class that i instantiate in my project with a @Bean annotation. Tha problem is inside this class i have an @Autowired to get another class of the second project, and when i try to run it is not able to solve this connection.

There is some way to call it?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example:

In my project A i have the next class:

```
@Component
public class Logger {

    private static final Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class);

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private DirectExchange exchange;
}
```

From the project B i get project A with a maven dependency.

In the project B i have:

```
public class OperatorSdkAmqpPollTests {

    private static final Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(OperatorSdkAmqpPollTests.class);

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;
}
```

When i run it it give the follow error:

```
Field exchange in com.minsait.cybersec.netvote.common.core.Logger required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange'
```

Add too that im running it under Spring Boot so RabbitTemplate is automatically defined, when i run a Test in project A it run whiout problems, DirectExchange is defined in project A in a class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AmqpConfig {

  @Bean
  public Queue worksQueue() {
    return new Queue("queue");
  }

  @Bean
  public DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("exchange");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could u please post some code. Could be more clearer

Comment: Do you get `NoClassDefFoundError` or `ClassNotFoundException` or some other errors? Share some error output or stacktrace.

Comment: I think is the typical "Not Bean for this @Autowired"
    
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: If someone have the same situation i found here the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345154/autowiring-between-separate-projects
Just need to add the class from the @Autowired in the classpath of the project that call:
`classpath*:com/my/base/package`

Answer (score 1):

In your project B your class `Logger` is not known as a bean since annotation `@Component` defines your class `Logger` in the scope of project A. The solution is very simple: Add a bean definition of your `Logger` class in XML configuration file for your Spring in project B. Then it will be known as Bean in yyour project B and everything will work.
So somewhere in MyOwnappricationContext.xml do this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

...

    <bean id="logger" name="logger" class="com.minsait.cybersec.my.package.from.project.a.Logger"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Well @Guillermo Garcia, If this helped you can you up-vote the answer?

Comment: OK, great, I am glad I was able to help